# Magical sub sequence of a string

Tags: c, strings

I have written C code for the below problem statement, for which I get the correct output, but I'm not sure whether the approach is right. Kindly go through and review my code.

> *Consider a string s, consisting of one or more of the following letters: a, e, i, o, and u.
>   We define a magical subsequence of s to be a sequence of letters derived from s that contains all five vowels in order. This means a magical subsequence will have one or more a's followed by one or more e's followed by one or more i's followed by one or more o's followed by one or more u's. For example, if s = "aeeiooua", then "aeiou" and "aeeioou" are magical subsequences but "aeio" and "aeeioua" are not.
>   Write a function to find length of longest magical subsequence with parameter string s.*
>
> Following should be the result:
>
> Input 1 - aeiaaioooaauuaeiou
>
> Output - 10
>
> Input 2 - aeiaaioooaa
>
> Output - 0 (as it does not contain u)

Hint - It is a program on Dynamic Programming

**My code**:

```
#define SIZE 5          //size of vowel array 'bptr'
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
typedef int BOOL;

//Function 'contains' checks whether the string contains all the vowels

BOOL contains(char *aptr,int cnt)
{
        char *bptr = "aeiou";
        int i = 0, j = 0;

        while(i < SIZE)
        {
        while(j < cnt)
        {
                if(bptr[i] == aptr[j])  //comparing
                {
                        i++;

                        if(i == SIZE)   // if all vowels are found return without further iteration
                        {
                                return TRUE;
                        }

                        j = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                        j++;
                }
        }

        if(j == cnt)    //if not found exit with value FALSE
        {
                printf("String does not contain letter %c, so magical sequence
cannot be constructed\n",bptr[i]);
                return FALSE;
            }

        }

}

//Function magic checks for the magical sequence

int magic(char *ptr)
{
        char ch = 'a';
        int count = 0;

        while(*ptr != '\0')
        {
                if(*ptr == 'a' || *ptr == 'e' || *ptr == 'i' || *ptr == 'o' || *ptr == 'u' )
                {
                                if( *ptr >= ch)
                                {
                                        count++;
                                        ch = *ptr;

                                }

                }
                        ptr++;
        }


        return count;
}

//Function 'length' calculates length of the input string

int length(char *ptr)
{
        int cnt = 0;


        while(*ptr != '\0')
        {
                cnt++;
                ptr++;
        }

        return cnt;
}

int main()
{
        int count = 0;
        char str[50];
        int strlength = 0;
        BOOL result = FALSE;

        printf("Enter string :");
        scanf("%s",&str);

        strlength = length(str);
        printf("Actual length of the string is %d\n",strlength);
        result = contains(str,strlength);

        if(result == TRUE)
        {
                count=magic(str);
                printf("Magic Length of the string '%s' is :%d\n",str,count);
        }
        else
        {
                printf("Magic length of the string '%s' is : %d\n",str,count);
        }



return 0;
}
```

Note : **Inbuilt functions not allowed**

Comment: The problem statement seems incomplete. It is missing an actual problem: are we looking for _a number_ of magical subsequences, or the _length of a longest one_, or something else?

Comment: rather than defining `true`, `false`, `BOOL`,  much better to use the header file: `stdbool.h`

Comment: @vnp I apologize, I missed that part! Well, I have updated the statement.

Comment: the question critera clearly shows nothing about additional output other than a single integer per input line (probably the question is from one of the online coding problems. so the posted code fails.

Comment: @user3629249 which additional output?

Comment: the `additional output` is those calls to `printf()` that are outputting anything but the single integer per line of input

Comment: @user3629249 I put those additional outputs for a better understanding of the code.  So are u saying doing so is an incorrect approach?

Comment: the extra outputs are fine for debugging, but not acceptable in the final code output

Comment: this example: `Input 1 - aeiaaioooaauuaeiou Output - 10` does not have sequence of 10 characters that match the criteria.  However, it does have a sequence of 5 characters (the last 5 characters) that does match, so, per the criteria,  the resulting output should be 5 not 10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69518/discussion-between-sanjana-jose-and-user3629249).

Answer (score 2):

This is not a review, but an extended comment. The code does not solve the problem correctly, so it is technically not ready for review.

As soon as the program encounters say `e` it decides that only `a`s seen before counts. That leads to a wrong result. For the string `aeiouaaeeiioouu` it prints 7 (which corresponds to `aeiou...uu` substring, but misses the `a...aaeeiioouu` substring of length 11).

Comment: In case of 'aeiouaaeeiioouu' the characters considered are AEIOUaaeeiiooUU (the capital ones) which gives the output 7. Why should it consider the A's after u? Because according to me the question says it shouldn't consider them (a...uAAeeiioouu) Isn't it?

Comment: I agree with vnp.  The problem statement asks for the longest magical subsequence.  The answer given uses a greedy algorithm and does not consider every possible subsequence.

Answer (score 0):

This function:

```
BOOL contains(char *aptr,int cnt)
```

Is quite inefficient.  You can achieve the same result by leveraging the `strchr` function in `string.h`.  Since you can't use that, here's an implementation that should work:

```
char* strchr(char* cptr,char c)
{
    char next;
    int index = 0;
    do
    {
        next = cptr[index];
        if(c == next)
        {
            return &cptr[index];
        }
        index++;
    }while(next != '\0');
    return NULL;
}

BOOL contains(char *aptr,int cnt)
{
        const char *bptr = "aeiou";
        int i = 0;
        for(;i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            if(strchr(aptr,bptr[i]) == NULL)
            {
                printf("String does not contain letter %c, so magical sequence cannot be constructed\n",bptr[i]);

                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: no 'inbuilt' functions allowed,  To me that means no string library functions, so no `#include <string.h>`  so this answer does not match the criteria in the question

Comment: @user3629249 - that requirement was added after my answer.  in any case it's fixed.

Comment: Yea sorry, I mentioned it later!

Answer (score 0):

1. Little value in `typedef int BOOL;` ....  Use `stdbool.h`.  `stdbool.h` does not bring in *Inbuilt functions*.

   ```
   // #define TRUE 1
   // #define FALSE 0
   // typedef int BOOL;
   // BOOL result = FALSE;

   #include <stdbool.h>
   bool result = false;
   ```
2. Use `const` when able for better self documentation, applicability, optimizations, and robust code.

   ```
   // char *bptr = "aeiou";
   const char *bptr = "aeiou";

   // int magic(char *ptr)
   int magic(const char *ptr)
   ```
3. Use an auto formatter.  Life is to short for weak manual formatting. IMO, 8 space indent is excessive, use 2, 4 or best: your group's coding standard.

   ```
   // while(i < SIZE)
   // {
   // while(j < cnt)
   // {

   while(i < SIZE)
   {
       while(j < cnt)
       {
   ```
4. The length of a *string* is always 0 or more.  The C standard library uses `size_t`, some unsigned type.  For you own "library", I recommend to follow that example and use `unsigned` or `unsigned long`.

   ```
   // int length(char *ptr) {
   //   int cnt = 0;
   unsigned length(const char *ptr)
        unsigned cnt = 0;
   ```
5. A simpler coding of `length()`

   ```
   unsigned length(const char *ptr) {
     const char *p = ptr;
     while (*p) p++;
     return p - ptr;
   }
   ```
6. Kudos on basic comments like `//Function 'contains' checks...`
7. The `printf("String does not contain ...` in `contains()` is a *very unusual place* for  such code.  The return value should indicate success/failure and the *calling routine* should print such a message.
8. The entire `contains(char *aptr,int cnt)` is dubious to its correct implementation. [@vnp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/181704/29485)
9. `scanf("%s",&str);` lack a width limitation.  Research `fgets()` for a robust solution.  `&` not needed.

   ```
   char str[50];
   // scanf("%s",&str);
   scanf("%49s",str);
   ```
10. The "Note : Inbuilt functions not allowed" would seem to prohibit `scanf()` and `printf()`.  I suspect "Inbuilt functions not allowed" is not completely correct.